href with Rich Text in tooltip
Issue:
A link:
\usepackage{hyperref}

Hello \href{https://www.google.com}{Google}

When hoverring the text, result:

Question:
How can I make link/href support Rich Text formatting for the tooltip, instead of just displaying the URL?
Usecase: The tooltip rich text would be more user-friendly: when mouse-hoverring, the tooltip:

My attempt so far:
I tried the macro Tooltip but it does not work well in Sumatra PDF. Probably because this is a custom control, while the \href uses Windows-built-in tooltip. The Windows's tooltip may not support Rich Text (I may be wrong here).
Environment

TeXstudio 4.8.4
Windows 10 x64 (22H2)


well if sumatra can not handle such annotations LaTeX can't change that.
